# Stop on last list-item after cycle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cycle

I have an ordered list, each list-item is cycled through displaying each one at a time. Fading in, then delaying for a set amount of time before fading out and displaying the next list-item in the same fashion. This is all working but when the last list-item is reached it returns to the start and runs in a continuous loop. Code below:

```
$(function() {
      var item = $('.test li').hide(),
          i = 0;
      (function cycle() {
          item.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(200, cycle);
          i = ++i % item.length;
      })();
  });
```

I added `if (i==10){return;}` above the line `item.eq(i).fadeIn(400)` which stopped the list-items from looping but the last list-item isn't displaying, presumably because its faded out.  How can I stop the last-item from not displaying. So it would fade in and that would be the end of the animation?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() { 

var item = $('.test li').hide(),
i = 0;

(function cycle() {
    if(i==item.length-1){
        item.eq(i).fadeIn(400);
        return;
    }
    item.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(2000)
              .fadeOut(200, cycle);
    i = ++i % item.length;
})();

});
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi, that works great thanks! I'll +1 you when I have enough rep! Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

Just make it only fade in when `i == 10` and then return?

```
(function cycle() {
    if (i == 10)
    {
        item.eq(i).fadeIn(400);
        return;
    }

    item.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(2000)
              .fadeOut(200, cycle);

    i = ++i % item.length;
})();
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the alternative way of solving this!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var item = $('.test li').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() {

    var curr = item.eq(i).fadeIn(400);

    if (i != item.length - 1) {
        curr.delay(2000).fadeOut(200, cycle);
        i = ++i % item.length;
    }

})();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/62zm9sa9/

Comment: This is another great version, I'm a novice with javascript so getting a few different versions of the same thing really helps thanks!